# Mutable types in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Of the basic types of python, which of those are mutable? From reviewing the docs it looks like:

- `list`
- `set` (though not `frozenset`)
- `dict`

Are the only mutable types, and everything else is immutable, but I wasn't able to find a definitive list on this. Is the above correct, or am I missing any python types that are mutable?

Comment: Why did  this question get negative voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Some of the mutable data types in Python are list, dictionary, set and user-defined classes.
2. On the other hand, some of the immutable data types are int, float, decimal, bool, string, tuple, and range.

https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a[Source][1]

Comment: "some of" does not sound like a definitive list.

Comment: The above LINK is not found

Comment: Here is some list :https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/ saying `dict` `set` `list`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [this page in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types). Here you can find all information about mutability of most common types in Python.

P. S. It is rather comment than answer, but my reputation is too small to comment.